# Fivetran Shopify Connector: Would like to extract and load the raw data from Shopify - which schema destination is the right one?

Tags: shopify, data-pipeline, fivetran

Which scheme to choose here to get all the raw data from my Shopify store?
The problem is, there is no exact description of what schemes are available?

Comment: If you mean GraphQL Schemas, the latest stable one is "2022-01". You could try that.

Answer (score 1):

Fivetran provides a specific ERD Schema where possible for the connectors it provides. You can select/unselect objects within the Schema tab, but the structure of the data is normalized and remains more or less constant.

[Shopify ERD Schema](https://fivetran.com/docs/applications/shopify#schemainformation)